# javascript, how to get all custom defined variables in window?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, can i  get all custom defined variables in window?
chrome cosole.log(window),it will show all properties...

```
for(var i in window){
    if(window.hasOwnProperty(i) && ...){
    }
}
```

Comment: A possible workaround - create an invisible iframe, loop through its properties and compare their names to the current window.

Comment: @naivists - +1 - Thats pretty much the only way imo.

Comment: Although I'd question *why* .. I guess for a developer tool?